# Bootstrap has something to show entire page on screen?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating some page with bootstrap and I want to show entire page in any screen size without user needs to scroll page up or down.
There's something in bootstrap to do this? The idea is something like the col classes, but for rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has no way of segmenting rows, as it takes up the necessary vertical space to display the content. You could apply a height constraint to the content in css:

```
.FullPage {
      max-height: 100%;
 }
```

However, limiting the space your content can take up isn't ideal as it can cause some nasty visual bugs. You can always stretch content out for the whole page but rarely constrain it vertically.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are looking for is this

`.FullPage {
  height: 100vh;
}`

this will size the `.FullPage` class to be 100% of the viewport's height